# Assistive Touch on iPad mini is getting turned off automatically

Tags: ipad, settings

Assistive Touch on my iPad mini is getting turned off automatically and when I go to Settings to check the status it will be in the off state.No-one is changing the status from on to off.I don't know why this happening.

Comment: General advice for any iOS generic weirdness would be -  Restart, then if no joy - [to iTunes] Sync; Backup; Restore.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please don't add superfluous content to your question to ‘bump’ it—if you wish to attract attention to your question, you can use a bounty if you have sufficient reputation.

Comment: @grgarside thanks for your suggestion and thanks for editing my question just becuase you are good here in this site that does not mean what you say was right :)

Comment: Just becoz it doesn't get more attention and I need to wait for 2 days I just edited the question @grgarside

Answer (score 1):

At the very bottom of the assistive preferences there's an option to put something on "shortcut" - meaning pressing the home button 3 times. 
Any chance you have that on assistive touch and do it by accident?